# How to remove tuple from the list?

Tags: python

everyone. I have a question about how to remove a Pythagorean triple from list in python.
The specific question ask me to create a list containing Pythagorean triples, but each triple can only occur once. My function is as following:

```
import numpy as np

def list_pythagorean_triples(amin,cmax):

    x=list(range(amin,cmax))
    y=[]
    for a in x:
        for b in x:
            c=np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
            if  c==int(c) and c<=cmax:
                s=a,b,int(c)
                y.append(s)      
    return y

U = list_pythagorean_triples(3,12)

U.sort()

print(U)
```

I got `[(3, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5), (6, 8, 10), (8, 6, 10)]` as the result. However, the expected one should be `[(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10)]`.

Any idea to modify the code? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set and order the values inside the tuples to avoid duplicates:

```
import numpy as np

def list_pythagorean_triples(amin,cmax):

    x=list(range(amin,cmax))
    y=set() # use a set
    for a in x:
        for b in x:
            c=np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
            if  c==int(c) and c<=cmax:
                s= (min(a,b), max(a,b), int(c))  # order tuple content by size
                y.add(s)  # sets use add, not append
    return list(y)

U = list_pythagorean_triples(3,12)

U.sort()

print(U)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10)]
```

Comment: Yeah, I got!  It is very helpful! Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to solve this:

You can sort the tuple before appending and then deduplicate

```
def list_pythagorean_triples(amin,cmax):
    x=range(amin,cmax)
    y=[]
    for a in x:
        for b in x:
            c=np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
            if  c==int(c) and c<=cmax:
                s=a,b,int(c)
                y.append(sorted(s))      
    return sorted(set(y))
```

Or better still, you can only use values of `b` that are larger than `a`.

```
def list_pythagorean_triples(amin,cmax):
    x=range(amin,cmax)
    y=[]
    for a in x:
        for b in range(a,cmax):
            c=np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
            if  c==int(c) and c<=cmax:
                s=a,b,int(c)
                y.append(s)      
    return y
```

Comment: Thank you for editing and answering! I got the right result~